# How would you stat a Chef Knife in AD&D?

Tags: weapons, adnd-1e

I've been thinking about this a lot. Whenever I look at or wield a chef knife, cut bones, saw through frozen meat, or use it to split boards, I get the distinct impression this deadly kitchen tool does not do the same damage as its smaller brothers like the steak knife, fillet knife, or bread/carving knives. A good chef knife cuts right into metal cans too.

So I've been wondering about the write up on a Chef Knife. I can't in good conscience call it a "knife", any more than those quasi-shortswords called Bowie Knives or Competition Cutters fit that description.

So what gives? How would you stat a Chef Knife? Call it a Dagger and move on?

Answer (score 7):

A Chef Knife is not made for combat. It is weighted and edged for carving and butchery, not making strikes against a foe. Having said that, there is plenty of overlap between the two tasks.

I would probably go with equal to a Dagger for that reason, and keeping things simple. Unless it is an Ogre's cooking "knife" or similar, in which case I might make it equivalent to a Shortsword.

If you are using the [optional weapon vs armour table,](https://www.therpgsite.com/showthread.php?26375-AD-amp-D1e-weapon-vs-armour-tables) you could rate the penalties worse than a dagger in most cases, and maybe add some bonus against unarmoured enemies. Then you might have an excuse to up-rate the damage without making a Chef Knife too special.

In my opinion though, if the provenance of the weapon is interesting or important, then make sure you describe it to add some depth to the game. Other than that, it is not really worth playing with +1/-1 kind of effects here, and you don't have much room to make changes before a Chef Knife would be a preferred weapon, or you have to start adding "realistic" drawbacks such as weak against armour or likely to break - for the kinds of damage and difference to the story you are talking about here, it is not worth the complexity of doing that. Not for most D&D at any rate.

> Whenever I look at or wield a chef knife, cut bones, saw through frozen meat, or use it to split boards, I get the distinct impression this deadly kitchen tool does not do the same damage as its smaller brothers like the steak knife, fillet knife, or bread/carving knives

You are likely here referring to modern realisations of the tool, made with high quality steel and re-designed over decades to be good to handle and versatile. That brings an entirely different perspective to how you might treat it in the game. If you wanted to import such a Chef Knife into AD&D with this modern feel, and limit its availability, I would suggest to make it a magic item, maybe equivalent to a +1 or even +2 magic dagger. Again, this keeps things simple - it calls out the superior quality of the modern item as being special, and doesn't add any complex rules.

Comment: "A Chef Knife is not made for combat."  For me, this just about covers it.  Too fragile to stand up, balanced wrong for throwing, won't hold its edge against armor.  Otherwise, they'd have been used instead of the Sykes-Fairbairn in WWII.

Comment: Yeah, even making it equivalent to a dagger is pretty generous - daggers are made for killing people, chef knives aren't.

Comment: @Miniman: I agree, but it's a reasonably common fantasy trope to have other blades stand in for real weapons and be effective in skirmish style combat. For instance https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WeaponOfChoice lists Chef Knife as an option. Not to mention completely unrealistic blade shapes and sizes used in much fantasy - although AD&D 1 is pretty old school and might care to be more accurate

Comment: @Miniman I seem to remember that by *Unearthed Arcana* that *AD&D* was making a distinction between a dagger and a knife, with the knife being inferior even to the dagger. Perhaps a more apt weapon equivalent?

Comment: Agree craftsmanship is a big factor. A sontaku or professional chef knife is balanced, expensive, and can be dropped without breaking. First difference I would make is probably change Piercing to Slashing. The "of quality" chef knife is P/S, costs as much as dagger of quality (say, 10gp instead of 2gp), and can be thrown because its balanced; Normal "chef knife" stays cheap quality 5sp, slash only, cannot be thrown, inflicts "dagger/d4" damage but has "brittle/breaks on max" damage quality. (chef knife in question was custom made by dwarves, finest quality damascus pattern with silver handles)

Answer (score 7):

### The AD&D rules don't address this, but Dragon Magazine had a very good "unofficial" article that covers weapons of opportunity like Chef's knives

There is an article in Dragon Magazine #97 that covers how to stat weapons of opportunity. The system involves assigning a given weapon a standard weapon equivalent and a category. The standard weapon equivalent is the statted weapon that most closely approximates the improvised weapon. So an oar approximates a quarterstaff for instance. As you rightly guess, the Chef or Butcher's knife is equivalent to a dagger.

The categories range from 1 to 3. Category 1 weapons are "same form, different purpose." Category 2 are "similar form" (the oar as a staff is category 2). Category 3 are "poor design for combat use" (example: a spading fork is a category 3 trident). The Butcher knife is given category 1, so it is Category 1/Dagger.

The categories are given a to hit penalty of minus the category number, and a speed adjustment of plus the category number. So a Butcher's knife is treated as a dagger with a -1 to hit penalty and a +1 weapon speed penalty. In all other respects, it is statted like its equivalent weapon, so 1d4 points of damage plus any strength modifier.

One of the comments to another answer mentioned that the *Unearthed Arcana* had stats for a "knife." This article uses the knife as a weapon equivalent for several weapons. A carving knife is a 1/knife, a paring knife is a 2/knife, and a chisel is a 3/knife. But Butcher's and Chef's knives are larger and counted as dagger equivalents. The article ran in the May 1985 issue of Dragon. The closest I can narrow down the *UA* publication date is between March and November of that year; however, most of *UA's* content had been previously published in Dragon with the assurance that it was official and would be in the new hardbound book. Given the fact that the author uses knife as a weapon equivalent, it seems reasonable to conclude that he was referring to the official *UA* knife rules when assigning weapons the equivalent of a statted knife.

Note that the article also presents special rules for using rocks and objects that cannot be approximated to a weapon, like a chair.

When this article was published, Dragon content was never considered official unless Gygax wrote it or explicitly dubbed it official in print, so this rule is not official 1E AD&D. I can say that I used the rules in this article for years playing AD&D. It gives the players sufficient reason to use purpose-built weapons whenever possible and is easy to implement on the fly when the PC picks up something unexpected. Here's a link to that issue: https://www.annarchive.com/files/Drmg097.pdf